# How to configure service reference not to change the List<string> parameter to Observable Collection in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, web-services, observablecollection

i have a method on service that as one of its parameters accepts List.

when i make a reference to said service in my silverlight app, it defines the parameter as ObservableCollection.

why does it do that, since this is not result of service call. and how do i configure it to use List<> but just for the said parameter, and not for all the results and parameters for rest of the methods in service.

service method:

```
public void deleteUsers(List<string> usernames){ ... }
```

auto generated reference in sliverlight app:

```
public void deleteUsers(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> usernames){ this.deleteUsersAsync(usernames,null);}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding service reference change in Advanced settings Collection Return Type from default ObservableCollection to List type. If you already have Service Reference added Right click your ServiceReference to open ServiceReference Configuration window. Change the Collection Return Type to System.List.

Comment: Doesn't that change all collections in the contract to `List`?  The question specifically asks that other collections continue with the default with only this one parameter of a specific method using `List`.

Comment: I think you missed Zak's **"and not for all the results and parameters for rest of the methods in service"** comment. This will change all enumeration return types.

Comment: I think it's impossible using default service reference generation tool. You should use custom wrappers for methods with List parameter, this wrappers could be generated from your own tool or written manual, and wrap APM of WCF.

Comment: I have temporarily solved the issue by using the observable collection to send the list to service, the framework seems to convert it back and forth without problems. but it does not make sense to use OC to send data, only to receive it, and then only when it is bound to something. it works...but the original question still remains unsolved.